# Sort breaking on subsequent render in React JS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-dom

I have an array `closedPeriods` that looks like this:

```
this.state = {
    selectedPortfolio: "",
    selectedPeriod: "",
    closedPeriods= [
        { portfolio: "foo", period: "june 2017", periodStart: "2017-06-01 00:00:00.000" },
        { portfolio: "foo", period: "may 2017", periodStart: "2017-05-01 00:00:00.000" },
        { portfolio: "bar", period: "may 2017", periodStart: "2017-05-01 00:00:00.000" }
    ]
}
```

I have a dropdown that selects the portfolio, then with the portfolio hand, I am rendering the period.

**Filter state array by portfolio**

```
let periodByPortfolio = [];
if(this.state.selectedPortfolio) {
    periodByPortfolio = this.state.closedPeriods
        .filter(item => item.portfolio === this.state.selectedPortfolio);
}
```

**Render periods belonging to portfolio:**

```
<label>Closed Periods</label>
<select id="closedPeriods">
    {periodByPortfolio.sort((previous, current) => current.periodStart - previous.periodStart)
        .map(option => {
            return (<option key={option.period} value={option.period}>{option.period}</option>);
    })}
</select>
```

TLDR:  My sorting function works on the first render.  As soon as I change Portfolio, and change back to the selected portfolio, my sorting becomes scrambled.  Why?

**EDIT**

Sorting issue was caused by one of the functions double-binding to the component.

```
// Bind 1
constructor() {
    this.filterOption = this.filterOption.bind(this);
}

// Bind 2
<select id="portfolio" value={this.props.portfolio} onChange={this.filterOption.bind(this, "portfolio")}>
```

Solution in Answer.

Comment: I'd hesitate to trust the type conversion on the date strings.  Do you get the same behavior if your Date.parse(date_string) in the sort function instead of just subtracting the number string?

Comment: your option key should be unique. and they are not. this can affect sorting

Comment: ?How do you select a portfolio ? where is the handler?

Comment: +1 to @TalAvissar 's comment,  I missed that before.  the key absolutely needs to be unique.  I've had elements not even render at all if key's are duplicates.  `.map((option, index) => .... key={\`${options.period}-${idx}\`}`

Comment: I figured it out.  I was double-binding one of the functions by mistake and somehow it was causing the sorting issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the second bind.  Also, you don't have to feed the function a target.  You can use the event object to handle the `name` part.

From

```
<select id="portfolio" value={this.props.portfolio} onChange={this.filterOption.bind(this, "portfolio")}>
```

To

```
<select id="portfolio" name="selectedPortfolio" value={this.props.portfolio} onChange={this.filterOption}>
```